# How to implement a Virtual host on AWS Linux Server?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, virtualhost

We already created a Linux server using Xampp. But we have 3-4 websites that we have to live there. But in xampp we live only one website in the root folder.
We are thinking about a Virtual host.
Below of our code:

**On httpd.conf file:**

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

We need help for setup httpd-vhosts.conf file.
What we will code there?

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, which is for questions relating to software development. You could ask it over on https://serverfault.com, but you will probably want to add some additional details (what documentation have you read? What have you tried so far?)